# Producing vectorial graphics in Python

Tags: python, vector-graphics

I need to produce high precision b&w vectorial graphics. The goal is to be able to print those graphics at scale, where lines can be as thin as 1 µm. Those graphics follow some geometric patterns, and I'm thinking about using Python to generate them. The output format doesn't really matter; it could be PDF, EPS, SVG, or something else...

Which library can you suggest to achieve that? Usually, I use Python 3, and PySide to make my GUI, but being able to display the graphics is optional.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, [PyCairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/tutorial/) is one of the best solutions for vector graphics in Python.
Another alternative is [PyX](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/).